# Validate user text

Tags: javascript, validation

I am trying to validate a text field so that they must enter a seven character value. The first character must be alphanumeric and the next six must be numeric. I have no problem with validating the length, but not sure how to achieve the rest. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

var regex = new RegExp('/^[a-zA-z]{1}[0-9]{6}$/') ;

Did you want to allow any spaces or special characters?

Whoops need to add in what Ivan said as I didnt realize you were unfamiliar with regular expressions.

Use

var regex = new RegExp('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}[0-9]{6}$/') ;

if(myString.match(regex)){
 "YOUR CODE" ;
}

Thanks Ivan missed that alpha part.

Comment: up vote from me, just change the first letter to [a-zA-Z0-9] as first char should be alphanumerical

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this: [Regular Expressions with JavaScript](http://www.learn-javascript-tutorial.com/RegularExpressions.cfm)

Comment: @singular at stackoverflow you can say thank you by upvoting or even accepting the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions...

```
if (myString.match(/^\w\d{6}$/))
  alert('Valid');
```

^ start of a string

\w any alphanumerical character + underscore (you can change it to [a-zA-Z0-9] for true alphanumeric)

\d any digit

{6} exactly 6 of them

$ end of a string

Comment: Good explanation. Also the ^ (carot) is the start of the string. Between the two of this we got this :P